# Deleting log files that are buried with powershell

Tags: powershell, delete-file, logfile

So I am trying to figure out a script to delete log files that are buried in many folders. Same path to the end folder minus the client name folder that changes. Below is an example of the code I thought would work which is failing horribly. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
gci X:\ -directory -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match \\temp\\company\\.+?\\AppData\\logfiles -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-20)}|Remove-Item -recurse -whatif
```

so the Directory is X and the path to the logfiles that I want to delete is `temp\company\NAME\appdata\logfiles` and the NAME folder is the one that could be one of any number of different clients names.

Error I keep getting.

```
At line:1 char:51
+ gci X:\ -directory -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match \\temp\\company\\.+?\\ ...
+                                                   ~
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-match' operator.
At line:1 char:52
+ gci x:\ -directory -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match \\Temp\\company\\.+?\\ ...
+                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '\\Temp\\company\\.+?\\AppData\\logfiles' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

Does anyone have any ideas what we are doing wrong or how to accomplish this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does it fail? Why is your regex not in string quotes?  What about `gci x:\temp\company\*\appdata\logfiles\* | where { ... date test} ` ?

Comment: I added the errors in that I get continuously

Comment: Then put your regex in string quotes `'\\temp\\company\\.+?\\AppData\\logfiles'`

Comment: That did not help unfortunately I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are because second argument to -match needs to be in quotes.

But there may be a way to do this without needing the complexity of your example.  Get-ChildItem can take both a -Path and a -Include (or -Filter) argument. So you might use something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -path c:\xxx -Include *log.tmp -Recurse | ... |  Remove-Item
```